# How unique would be guid generated using this code

Tags: apex

I wanted to have guiid generated in apex. Here is a question which answers this
[How to generate a GUID/UUID?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4073/how-to-generate-a-guid-uuid?rq=1)

How unique would the guiid generated using the code suggested by @rev

```
Blob b = Crypto.GenerateAESKey(128);
String h = EncodingUtil.ConvertTohex(b);
String guid = h.SubString(0,8)+ '-' + h.SubString(8,12) + '-' + h.SubString(12,16) + '-' + h.SubString(16,20) + '-' + h.substring(20);
```

What is the probability of getting a duplicate ?

Comment: I can't claim to understand all the bitwise operations, but shouldn't the complexity just be `[possible characters] ^ [number of characters]`, which in this case is `16 ^ 32`, or `2 ^ 128`?

Comment: It is hard to calculate probability without knowing implementation of how Crypto.GenerateAESKey works. I did 10 series of experiments by generating of 100k of guids by that way, and there are no duplicates, even between results of those experiments

Comment: Wow.. no dupes for 100k guids, i guess its quite safe to use :)