# Why is my trigger hitting "Too many query rows: 50001"?

Tags: trigger

I have a couple of processes that occur when a Contact is created, along with this trigger. It used to work fine before but suddenly I'm getting these and I can't create a Contact:

Error Occurred: The flow tried to update these records: null. This error occurred: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: RF_CreateUuidWhenResetPassword: System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001. For details, see API Exceptions.

What's wrong with the trigger?

```
trigger RF_CreateUuidWhenResetPassword on Contact (before update, before insert) {

    if(Trigger.isUpdate){
        Map<string, Contact> conMap = new Map<string, Contact>([select Password_Reset_Token__c, name
                                                              from Contact
                                                              where Password_Reset_Token__c <> null]);
        For (Contact c: Trigger.new){
            If (c.Is_Password_Reset__c == True){
                Blob b = Crypto.GenerateAESKey(128);
                String h = EncodingUtil.ConvertTohex(b);
                string UUID = h.SubString(0,8)+ '-' + h.SubString(8,12) + '-' + h.SubString(12,16) + '-' + h.SubString(16,20) + '-' + h.substring(20);

                While(conMap.get(UUID) != NULL){//To avoid duplication of UUID
                    b = Crypto.GenerateAESKey(128);
                    h = EncodingUtil.ConvertTohex(b);
                    UUID = h.SubString(0,8)+ '-' + h.SubString(8,12) + '-' + h.SubString(12,16) + '-' + h.SubString(16,20) + '-' + h.substring(20);
                }//end while

                c.Password_Reset_Token__c = UUID;
            }//end if
        }//end for
    }
    if(Trigger.isInsert){
        Map<string, Contact> conMap = new Map<string, Contact>([select Password_Reset_Token__c, name
                                                              from Contact
                                                              where Password_Reset_Token__c <> null]);
        For (Contact c: Trigger.new){

                Blob b = Crypto.GenerateAESKey(128);
                String h = EncodingUtil.ConvertTohex(b);
                string UUID = h.SubString(0,8)+ '-' + h.SubString(8,12) + '-' + h.SubString(12,16) + '-' + h.SubString(16,20) + '-' + h.substring(20);

                While(conMap.get(UUID) != NULL){//To avoid duplication of UUID
                    b = Crypto.GenerateAESKey(128);
                    h = EncodingUtil.ConvertTohex(b);
                    UUID = h.SubString(0,8)+ '-' + h.SubString(8,12) + '-' + h.SubString(12,16) + '-' + h.SubString(16,20) + '-' + h.substring(20);
                }//end while
                c.Password_Reset_Token__c = UUID;
        }//end for
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the Password_Reset_Token__c value ever get removed at anytime from the Contacts in your system?

Comment: It won't be removed but it might get changed. @DanKowalski

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Code you have currently will cause issues down the line as more and more contacts get added to your system. I would suggest doing something like the following.

```
Map<string, Id>TempConList = new Map<String, Id>();

For (Contact c: Trigger.new){

Blob b = Crypto.GenerateAESKey(128);
String h = EncodingUtil.ConvertTohex(b);
string UUID = 
    h.SubString(0,8)+ '-' + 
    h.SubString(8,12) + '-' + 
    h.SubString(12,16) + '-' + 
    h.SubString(16,20) + '-' + 
    h.substring(20);

TempConList.put(UUID, c.id);

}

List<Contact> ConList = [select Password_Reset_Token__c, name
                            from Contact
                            where Password_Reset_Token__c IN:TempConList.keySet()];
```

That will only get the ones that have a match and you can pick those out and not update them. That would cut down on your query size.

Answer (score 1):

The SOQL statement:

```
[select Password_Reset_Token__c, name
                             from Contact
                             where Password_Reset_Token__c <> null]
```

will require a table scan to resolve. Your org has probably just passed 50,000 contacts.

You will need to think of a different strategy that queries Contacts based on values in the trigger set or possibly date ranges so that indexes are used.

See [SFDC doc](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/rel1/doc/en-us/static/pdf/salesforce_query_search_optimization_developer_cheatsheet.pdf) on query optimization

Comment: I did a Contact report.. we have 17000+ Contacts

Comment: as @Markpond said, the transaction limit is 50,000 SOQL rows so whatever starts this transaction may be invoking multiple trigger invocations that exceed the total transaction limit. Look at the debug log and see where the soql queries are occurring. for example: Workflows that do field updates on Contact will re-execute the trigger

Answer (score 1):

I'd put money on the assumption that you've got more than 50,000 contacts being queried here in the collection that you later use for detecting duplicate UUIDs.

```
select Password_Reset_Token__c, name
from Contact
where Password_Reset_Token__c <> null
```

You should probably use a 'unique' constraint on the `Password_Reset_Token__c` field instead. This will be a database level enforcement and will require you to query no Contacts in your trigger and also let you cut out most of that trigger's code.

This will guarantee uniqueness but will prevent a successful commit of any record which has a duplicate value to another record already in the system, which you'll likely have to handle.

One way to handle that pattern would be to invert the logic of your trigger like this:

```
if (Trigger.isInsert) {


    // collection to allow matching of uuids to Contacts
    Map<String, Contact> uuidContactMap = new Map<String, Contact>();

    // generate a UUID and set the field value on the contact coming through the trigger
    for (Contact c: Trigger.new) {

        Blob b = Crypto.GenerateAESKey(128);
        String h = EncodingUtil.ConvertTohex(b);
        String UUID = h.SubString(0,8)+ '-' + h.SubString(8,12) + '-' + h.SubString(12,16) + '-' + h.SubString(16,20) + '-' + h.substring(20);

        // set the field with the generated UUID
        c.Password_Reset_Token__c = UUID;

        // store the UUID in our map to allow us to check for duplicates
        uuidContactMap.put(UUID, c);
    }

    // quick reference to the UUIDs
    Set<Id> uniqueUUIDs = :uuidContactMap.keyset();

    // homework for the reader:
    // check for collection size equality - should have one key per contact in the collection
    // inequality means a duplicated UUID was created
    // --> handle dupes created within this collection of 200 while generating UUIDs

    system.assertEquals(trigger.new.size(), uniqueUUIDs.size(), 'There was a duplicate created within the trigger code above.');

    // check for duplicate keys already in the database
    Map<Id, Contact> conMap = new Map<Id, Contact>([Id
                                              , Password_Reset_Token__c 
                                              FROM Contact 
                                              WHERE Password_Reset_Token__c IN :uniqueUUIDs]);

    if (!conMap.isEmpty()) {
        // if a record is found in the query above, regenerate the UUID for the Contact here in trigger.new
        // and check again and recreate until no duplicate is found
        system.assert(false, 'There was a duplicate found in the database matching one of our UUIDs.');
    }
}
```

Comment: TBH, a dev wrote this and I'm trying to fix it myself without incurring cost. The field is already unique but I think he wanted to unique-ify it at creation as well so as not to throw a flow error at the point of creation? Not sure if I'm talking rubbish. Also, we just seem to have 17000+ Contacts so I'm not sure how we're hitting the limit. Will try your code, thx

Comment: You're not likely to have dupes with that code (which came from here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4073/how-to-generate-a-guid-uuid) but I wanted you to be aware that it was possible and handle it if you can. You might have just 17000 contacts in the org, but you're also probably not the only one with a trigger on Contact doing work and you all share the same limits.