# Do Apex Transaction have a unique Id (like Batch Ids)?

Tags: apex, platform-event, transaction

I am working on a Platform Event based Logging Framework (based on the ideas of [Andrew Fawcett's Dreamforce session](https://www.salesforce.com/video/1779405/)).

I want to visually group Log entries of the same transaction or batch.

Batch jobs all share a common Id. **Is there something comparable for normal synchronous transactions?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

New, as of Winter 21 you can do this by calling

```
Request.getCurrent().getRequestId()
```

See https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_apex_Runtime_Detection.htm

And https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Request.htm

Comment: Is there a known length? I'd like to use this on a sObject-based logging record.  A quick experiment running as Anonymous Apex looks like it is 22-characters, but would love to have a reference. The closest I've found is in the Event Log Examples for REQUEST_ID are all 22 characters. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.224.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_supportedeventtypes.htm

Answer (score 2):

No. You could generate one yourself using UUID, or some other concept. But at least as far as is documented and what we can access, synchronous transactions do not have a job Id. If you look at [Daniel Ballinger's post on obscure key prefixes](http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html), none seem a likely match, other than maybe `SyncTransactionLog`, which is not documented in the `SOAP API Developer Guide`.

If you want to use UUID, I'd take the code in [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/4073/2995) and adapt it slightly.

```
public with sharing class UUID
{
    public static String generate()
    {
        String rawId = EncodingUtil.ConvertTohex(Crypto.GenerateAESKey(128));
        return String.join(new List<String> {
            rawId.subString(0,8),
            rawId.subString(8,12),
            rawId.subString(12,16),
            rawId.subString(16,20),
            rawId.substring(20)
        }, '-');
    }
}
```

Then you can just lazy load an Id in this class, but it would likely be more appropriate to set such a property in your `TransactionLog` class or similar.

Comment: You are just AWSOME, Adrian!

Comment: I leave it open until Salesforce provides this natively. It's on the roadmap. I didn't use @Adrians solutions as a simple Timestamp was sufficient in my case.

Comment: Interesting. You could get multiple transactions at the same time though, no? Curious to see if it is written down anywhere that this is on the roadmap. Do you have a reference? :)

Comment: See my recent tweet where Andy Fawcett mentions that Chris Peterson is working on that.

Comment: @RobertSösemann, can you please tell how you implement that using a timestamp?

Comment: @NoorAShuvo see my code here https://github.com/rsoesemann/apex-unified-logging