# Apex Interview ID

Tags: apex

Is there such a thing as an Apex Interview ID? much like flows & process builders have interview ID's?

I'm looking at logging out to a log database and if there already is a unique Id, I could use that would make life easier.

Comment: This might help you - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/246644/do-apex-transaction-have-a-unique-id-like-batch-ids

Comment: hmmm, interesting is this unique?

Comment: Yes , from the docs (Present in answer link) - The Request ID is universally unique and is captured in the debug logs triggered by the request.

Comment: Do consider upvoting if it helped you.