# Export Event standard Classic button component for Lightning not working

Tags: apex, visualforce, email

I'm working with a quick action that retrieves Event record information and send an email with an .ics related file as attachment.

This is my vfp for .ics file:

```
<apex:page standardController="Event" ContentType="text/calendar;charset=utf-8">
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//salesforce.com//Calendar//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:<apex:outputText value="{!Event.id}"/>
DTSTAMP:<apex:outputText value="{!SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(NOW()),':',''),'-',''),' ','T')}"/>
SUMMARY:<apex:outputText value="{!Event.Subject}"/>
CATEGORIES:salesforce.com
CREATED:<apex:outputText value="{!SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(NOW()),':',''),'-',''),' ','T')}"/>
LAST-MODIFIED:<apex:outputText value="{!SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(NOW()),':',''),'-',''),' ','T')}"/>
STATUS:CONFIRMED
DTSTART:<apex:outputText value="{!SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(Event.StartDateTime),':',''),'-',''),' ','T')}"/>
DURATION:PT60M
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
</apex:page>
```

And this is my quick action controller method that generates and send the email:

```
        //Get email attachment 
        PageReference iscVFP = Page.IscFileVFP;
        iscVFP.getParameters().put('id', recordId);
        try{
            List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailLIST = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
            for(Contact cnt : contactLIST){
                //Attachment
                Blob body = Test.isRunningTest() ? Blob.valueOf('test') : iscVFP.getContent();
                Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
                attach.setContentType('text/calendar;charset=utf-8');
                attach.setFileName('testfile.ics');
                attach.setInline(false);
                attach.Body = body;    
                //Body
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                mail.setUseSignature(false);
                mail.setToAddresses(new List<String>{cnt.Email});
                mail.setSubject('Test ics');
                mail.setHtmlBody('This is a test');

                mail.setFileAttachments(new List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment>{attach}); 
                emailLIST.add(mail);
            }
            if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
                Messaging.sendEmail(emailLIST); 
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return false;
        }
```

And it's working an sending email with attachment but it's not opening the file it it's generated from quick action. Also if I compare both files (one from standard classic 'Export Event' button and the one coming from my quick action) they look different on UID param:

**Standard Classic:**

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//salesforce.com//Calendar//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:e8bc21b4-3bbf-44d1-84e1-481111fbc5f2
DTSTAMP:20190318T114929Z
SUMMARY:Call
CATEGORIES:salesforce.com
CREATED:20190318T114929Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20190318T114929Z
STATUS:CONFIRMED
DTSTART:20190318T120000Z
DURATION:PT60M
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

**Quick action:**

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//salesforce.com//Calendar//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:00U6E000002YXaqUAG
DTSTAMP:20190318T114929Z
SUMMARY:Call
CATEGORIES:salesforce.com
CREATED:20190318T114929Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20190318T114929Z
STATUS:CONFIRMED
DTSTART:20190318T120000Z
DURATION:PT60M
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

**What sould I pass for UID param? Or is there something else that I'm not doing right that could fix this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`UID`](https://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/uid.html) parameter in iCal format is a globally unique identifier. I think the Salesforce Id *should* work there. It doesn't meet the **RECOMMENDED** spec of being an RFC-822 compliant identifier; you could postfix a hostname to comply with that recommendation.

However, it sounds like whatever client software you're using doesn't like *something* about your file, and the only difference in the text content is the format of the UID field. To eliminate that variable, I would suggest using a [UUID](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4073/how-to-generate-a-guid-uuid) as the UID content. If that doesn't solve the issue, then the problem isn't with the file content but something around its transmission or your local software.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I was about to try using UID but I wanted to know first if there's something I could be doing wrong or needs to be redone before that. I tried that but also try to generate blob body based on a string instead of VFP and now it's working.