# Generate Unique URL in salesforce

Tags: force.com, force.com-sites

I have a requirement where internal users have to generate/frame an unique URL via email which will be used by external user (Not a salesforce user). 
The URL should open a form and creates a record in backend when user submits the form. The tricky part here is no other user should be able to use this url or should not be authorized to use this. I need to authenticate the user who opens this url without creating an User record in salesforce.

My plan is to share public site URL which will authenticate the user based on security question and takes the user to form.

I would like to know if there is any feature or process using which we can accomplish the above.

Comment: You can use salesforce sites for this. Any user can open sites. Try that

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I can provide salesforce site url to external user. But I need some authentication mechanism so that only the user to whom the url has been shared should use. No other users should not be able to use the url.

Comment: I'm interested in a solution for this as well.  We are planning on developing something similar in the near future that will provide a one-time-use link to access a page on our public site.  I'm planning to use a random key that I will attach to the contact record: the VF page that will display will verify that the parameters sent are the ContactId and the RandomKey - and then will show the page and clear the RandomKey -- so the link could never be used again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Contact record (assuming that Contact is the base of who is being sent the link) - create two fields: "SecurityQuestion" and "RandomKey"

When you send the invite to submit the form, set the "SecurityQuestion" to the answer you want the Contact to enter, and set "RandomKey" to a [randomly generated GUID](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4073/how-to-generate-a-guid-uuid).

The email to the Contact would contain a link with parameters like this:
    https://theUrlOfYourSite/?cid=CONTACTID&key=RANDOMKEY
where you'd replace the CONTACTID and RANDOMKEY appropriately.

Then, when the Contact clicks the link, the VisualForce page that handles the display of the form would first verify that the ContactId and RandomKey match correctly, and then ask for the Security Question answer.  If the submitted answer also matches, allow the form submission and also clear out the RandomKey on the Contact record.  That will prevent the link from being used again unless a new link is generated.

Comment: Paul, This is exactly what I need. Thanks for your reply. I will tweak this a little bit to make it work for my requirement.