# How to verify non-deterministic field values in a unit test that does no DML?

Tags: fflib, apexmock

*for fflib / apexmocks users*

Let's say you have a class/method that inserts new objects where a field value is non-deterministic, say, a UUID

```
public class AccountsServiceImpl {
  public void makeAccount() {
    fflib_ISobjectUnitOfWork uow = Application.UnitOfWork.newInstance();
    uow.registerNew(new Account (Name = UUID.getV4());
    uow.commitWork();
  }
}
```

The method `UUID.getV4()` [constructs a V4-compliant UUID](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/223381/2602) using a **Cryptographic random number**

The normal testmethod ApexMocks pattern for verifying an sobject would be:

```
fflib_ApexMocks mocks = new fflib_ApexMocks();

fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork mockUow = (fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork) mocks.mock(fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork.class);  // the mock UnitOfWork
Application.UnitOfWork.setMock(mockUow); // injected for the factory to see

// When code-under-test executed
AccountsServiceImpl.makeAccount();

// Then verify Account fields constructed as expected
((fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork)mocks.verify(mockUow,mocks.times(1).description('account should be constructed as expected')))
        .registerNew(fflib_Match.sObjectWith(new Map<SObjectField,Object> {
            Account.Name => ??  // what goes here ??
    }));
```

But, you have no constant to assign to the Matcher `sObjectWith` for field `Account.Name` as the value is determined randomly.

Assuming you wish to avoid DML in this unit test method, what do you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches to solve this

### Dependency-injection of mock UUIDs into the UUID class

There would be all sorts of ways to do this including:

- Modifying the UUID class to use an interface to supply UUIDs. The production code would use a concrete implementation that uses random numbers but the testmethod would inject an object that returned a predictable set of UUIDs, in a known ascending pattern. This is roughly analogous to the HttpMockCallout interface used to test callout responses

Your testmethod now looks like:

```
public class UUIDMocker {

  static Integer timesCalled = 0;
  public String uuidGenerator() {
     timesCalled++;
     return '00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000' + i; // assumes called 0-9 times; could be cleverer
  }
}
...
fflib_ApexMocks mocks = new fflib_ApexMocks();

fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork mockUow = (fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork) mocks.mock(fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork.class);  // the mock
Application.UnitOfWork.setMock(mockUow); // injected for the factory to see

// When code-under-test executed
AccountsServiceImpl.makeAccount();

// Then verify Account fields constructed as expected
((fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork)mocks.verify(mockUow,mocks.times(1).description('account should be constructed as expected')))
        .registerNew(fflib_Match.sObjectWith(new Map<SObjectField,Object> {
            Account.Name => '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001'
    }));
```

### Use ApexMocks ArgumentCaptor

ArgumentCaptors allow the object passed to `uow.registerNew(theSObject)` to be inspected during the testmethod execution. This works because since we are mocking the UnitOfWork object, the ApexMocks (i.e. `Test.StubAPI`) framework is capturing all of the arguments passed to every method in the mocked object (the `uow`). As the framework has captured the arguments, they can be inspected later.

The syntax is a bit wonky but it goes like this:

```
fflib_ApexMocks mocks = new fflib_ApexMocks();

fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork mockUow = (fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork) mocks.mock(fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork.class);  // the mock UnitOfWork
Application.UnitOfWork.setMock(mockUow); // injected for the factory to see

// When code-under-test executed
AccountsServiceImpl.makeAccount();

// Define an ArgumentCaptor
fflib_ArgumentCaptor capturedArg    = fflib_ArgumentCaptor.forClass(SObject.class); // N.B. type is ignored, see comments in fflib_ArgumentCaptor class
    

// Capture the argument in the registerNew call; we don't know how many registerNew calls so make sure to get all of them
((fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork) mocks.verify(mockUow,mocks.atLeastOnce()))
                               .registerNew((SObject)capturedArg.capture());

// Since the code under test could have called registerNew many times, get all values   
Object[] actualArgAsObjects = capturedArg.getAllValues();

// Since the code under test could have done registerNew for Sobjects besides Account, 
// filter out only those that are Accounts 
    for (Integer i = 0; i < actualArgAsObjects.size(); i++) { // for every registerNew()
        if (actualArgAsObjects[i] instanceof Account) {
            // Cast from Object to Account to make it easier to work with
            Account actualRegisterNewAccountArg = (Account) actualArgAsObjects[i];
            Pattern uuidV4Pattern = Pattern.compile('[\\w]{8}-[\\w]{4}-4[\\w]{3}-[89ab][\\w]{3}-[\\w]{12}');
            System.assertEquals(true,uuidV4Pattern.matcher(actualRegisterNewAccountArg.Name).matches(),'Account.Name is not a UUID');
        }
    }
```

***Notes***

1 - It is left to the reader to add assertions to verify that each constructed Account in the transaction has a different UUID generated (assuming the code under test creates 2+ Accounts)
2 - On the line `fflib_ArgumentCaptor capturedArg    = fflib_ArgumentCaptor.forClass(SObject.class);` you would think you could do this:

```
fflib_ArgumentCaptor capturedArg    = fflib_ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Account.class);
```

and capture only the `registerNew` of Account SObjects, ignoring any `registerNew` for Contact, Order, etc.  But this sadly doesn't work as per this comment in the `fflib_ArgumentCaptor` class

> - The Type is IGNORED because we can't determine an object instance's Type at runtime unlike in Java.
> - Rigorous type checking may be introduced in a future release, so you should specify the expected argument type correctly.